# Search bar producing a synthetic event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search bar component that should take the value of the input, however I am using useState for my getters and setters and i am a bit confused as it is reported an error of [image]

Below is my component, can you spot the erorr?

```
const SuppliersNavBar = (props) => {

const { classes } = props;
const [search, setSearch] = useState();

const updateSearch = (event) => {
setSearch({ search: event.target.value });
console.log(event);
};

return (
<Fragment><Fab className={classes.addCircle} style={{ float: 'right', 
marginRight: 10, marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: '#3B70BC', color: 
'white' }} onClick={() => { this.props.history.push('/'); }} 
id="addCircle" ><Add /></Fab>
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Grid container direction="row"
          justify="flex-start"
          alignItems="center">
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
            <div className={classes.grow} />
            <div className={classes.search} aria-label="search bar">
              <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                <Search id="searchIcon" />
              </div>
              <InputBase
                aria-label="search bar"
                value={search}
                onChange={updateSearch.bind(this)}
                placeholder="Search"
                classes={{
                  root: classes.inputRoot,
                  input: classes.inputInput,
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </div>
</Fragment>
);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events in React are handled through object pooling meaning that events aren't readable through the console. You can call `event.persist()` and you will be able to see it. Please look at this page for further information. https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html